# Setting axis line offset?

Tags: pgfplots

I was wondering if it was possible to easily detach the axis lines from each other.

From this piece of code,

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    xmin=-6.3, xmax=6.3,
    ymin=-2.3, ymax=2.3,
    ]
    \addplot {2*sin(deg(x))};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

how could I achieve to get something like the bottom left plot of this example?

[image]

I would like to remove the line between the first tick of the x axis and the y axis line: is there a way to independently offset the axes and/or "set off" the corner where axes cross each other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can modify the `every non boxed x axis` style introducing shifts for the axis, labels and ticks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\newlength\xaxisoffset
\newlength\yaxisoffset
\setlength\xaxisoffset{-10pt}
\setlength\yaxisoffset{-10pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
every non boxed x axis/.style={
xtick align=center,
x axis line style={yshift=\xaxisoffset,-stealth},
y axis line style={xshift=\yaxisoffset,-stealth},
yticklabel style={xshift=\yaxisoffset},
xticklabel style={yshift=\xaxisoffset},
xtick style={very thin,yshift=\xaxisoffset},
ytick style={very thin,xshift=\yaxisoffset},
},
xmin=0, xmax=7.3,
ymin=-2, ymax=2.3,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left
]
\addplot[blue,domain=0:7] {2*sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The lengths `\xaxisoffset` and `\yaxisoffset` allow you to control each axis independently.

Comment: @Gonzalo, I do not want to open a new question for this, so here goes: If  I want to hide the axis arrow heads, removing *both* 'stealth' keywords hides only the x-axis arrow. Any suggestions?

Comment: @noe if no shifting for the axes is needed. it's enough to use `axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left`; if the shift must be preserved, you need `x axis line style={yshift=\xaxisoffset},
y axis line style={xshift=\yaxisoffset},
yticklabel style={xshift=\yaxisoffset},
xticklabel style={yshift=\xaxisoffset},
xtick style={very thin,yshift=\xaxisoffset},
ytick style={very thin,xshift=\yaxisoffset},
},
xmin=0, xmax=7.3,
ymin=-2, ymax=2.3,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line*=left`