# How to make Tufte style 'data based labels', showing the maximum and minimum of the data

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a graph where the maximum and minimum of the plotted data are reflected on an axis and the axis line stops after that value. Although sometimes I want noisy data to appear at larger/smaller values.

I tried to offset the axis as was suggested in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108885/setting-axis-line-offset) post. The problem you can see is that in this case I want the axis to go from -0.1 to -0.7 with ticks at these positions. The problem is that if you have noisy data it gets clipped after ymin and ymax.

I've provided a manually edited example on the bottom.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\newlength\xaxisoffset
\setlength\xaxisoffset{-10pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        every non boxed x axis/.style={ %Shifts the x axis downwards
            x axis line style={yshift=\xaxisoffset},
            xticklabel style={yshift=\xaxisoffset},
            xtick style={very thin,yshift=\xaxisoffset},
        }, 
        xmin = -.09, xmax=.09,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        ymin = -0.7, ymax = -0.08,
        ytick={-.1, -.7},
        ]
        \addplot[smooth, black] table[x=B, y=R_NL] {SV018_RR2B2.dat};
        \end{axis};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot from code]
[image: plot I want]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Clipping can be disabled by option `clip=false`.
- The order of magnitude of the x labels (·10<sup>-2</sup>) is moved down twice; `x tick scale label style={yshift=-\xaxisoffset}` compensates it.

Full example file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\newlength\xaxisoffset
\setlength\xaxisoffset{-40pt}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}  
    \begin{axis}[    
      clip=false,  
      every non boxed x axis/.style={% Shifts the x axis downwards  
        x axis line style={yshift=\xaxisoffset},    
        xticklabel style={yshift=\xaxisoffset},    
        x tick scale label style={yshift=-\xaxisoffset},    
        xtick style={very thin,yshift=\xaxisoffset},    
      },   
      xmin = -.09, xmax=.09, 
      axis x line=bottom,  
      axis y line*=left,  
      ymin = -0.7, ymax = -0.1,  
      ytick={-.1, -.7},  
    ]    
      \addplot[smooth, black] coordinates {  
         (-.08, -.5) (-.06, -.8) (-.04, -.5) (-.02, -.7)  
         (-.0, -.1) (.02, -.4) (.04, -.05) (.06, -.2) (.08, -.75)  
      };  
    \end{axis};    
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]