# Double y-axis in pgfplot for polar plots

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

Does anyone has a clue about how to "double" y-axis in polar plots using pgfplots? This question is related to this previous one: [Polar plot using pgfplots/tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267938/polar-plot-using-pgfplots-tikz/280852#280852)
Until now I only got the top part (as shown in @Jake answer on the previous post). I would like to mirror it to the bottom part also (as in first figure of the related post).

Thanks in advance