# Producing an a transducer directivity pattern with dB scale

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

Edit: Question updated to address comments from Willie Wong. The directiviy pattern now plots as I've added 90 to each value. I need the y-axis to read from -N to 0 dB where N will vary, however when I do this by setting ymin=40 as per the MWE my polar plot changes shape.

I'm trying to produce a directivity pattern which will look similar to this, except I wish for my x-axis to run between -90 and 90. [directivity http://www.fao.org/3/a-aa044e/AA044E47.gif](http://www.fao.org/3/a-aa044e/AA044E47.gif)
However I'm struggling to get the plot set up right. I had a look around and there's a [similar question, but for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137222/a-half-polar-plot-directivity-pattern-with-db-scale-and-negative-angle-values).
My amplitude data has a maximum value of 0 dB and min somewhere around -90 dB. When I try to plot it using the MWE below, it's just not quite right...

[image: MWEaxis]

My MWE is below. Note the contents of polartest.csv aren't really important as the axis are what's troubling me. y values extend between -90 and +90 and x values between -90 and 0

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[xmin=-90,xmax=90,rotate=-90,xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,xtick={-90,-45,...,90},xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},x dir=reverse,yticklabel style={anchor=south, yshift=-6mm},ymin=-60, ymax=0,y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+60},y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-60}]
\addplot  [no markers, blue] table [x=coord, y=ampPos, col sep=comma] {polartest.csv};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you edit your csv file to include some data points where the amplitude has a positive dB value? I am guessing that since you included negative dB values, the graph is actually appearing in the bottom half plane (conventionally polar plots with negative radial values plots the corresponding positive radial value with a 180 degree phase shift)

Comment: alternatively, what if you plot instead of y=amp the value of y=amp+90?

Comment: Question edited to respond to the advice from Willie Wong

Comment: This looks very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267938/polar-plot-using-pgfplots-tikz. Could you take a look to see if the answers there help?

Comment: Jake I had a look at that question before posting, but I don't think I realised how relevant it was. I've added this code to my MWE: `ymin=-60, ymax=0,
y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+60},y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-60}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments from @Jake I set-up the axis in the following way:

```
\begin{polaraxis}    
[xmin=-90,xmax=90,rotate=-90,xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
xtick={-45,-20,0,20,45},xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90},x dir=reverse,yticklabel style={anchor=south, yshift=-6mm},ymin=-40, ymax=0,
y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+40},y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-40}]
```

This allows me to plot directivity data saved in dB values with a maximum of 0. Directivity runs from -90 to +90 degrees. Note depending on the plot change the number 40 above to the desired dyanmic range of the plot.